# Accessing the table fields with relation yii2

Tags: yii2

Model `users` has onetomany relation with `category`

```
 public function getCategory() 
    {
         return $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_id']);
    }
```

I am not being able to access the fields of category using this relation.

```
   public function actionGetResults()
            {
                $results = users::find()->where(['user_id' =>8])
                                        ->with('category')
                                        ->all(); 

                echo "<pre>"; print_r($results);
            }
```

`$results` here shows an array with fields of category. i.e category_name, category_id etc. but if i do this:

```
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($results->category_name);
```

it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, since relation type is has many, `category` name is misleading and it's better to use `categories`.

Second, you are accessing related field wrong. `$results` is an array of `User` models and `categories` property of each model contains an array of related `Category` models to that user.

Use nested `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($results as $user) {
    foreach ($user->categories as $category) {
        var_dump($category->name);
    }
}
```

Or to get the name of the first user's first category:

```
$results[0]->categories[0]->name
```

Note that the second approach is only for demonstration purposes and can fail with `Undefined index` error if user or / and category does not exist.

Read [Working with Relational Data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data) for more info.